# Get a StreamReader from a resource file in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a text file named `dictionary.txt` in the Resource folder of a Xamarin Android project. I need a StreamReader to read the file. I improvised the following code to get it:

```
Stream res = Resources.OpenRawResource(Resource.Raw.dictionary);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
res.CopyTo(ms);
ms.Position = 0;
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8, true);
```

Is there a better way to get a usable `StreamReader` from a resource file? It seems converting and copying the stream several times may make the code slow.

Comment: Hi, it seems your shared code is the good solution, else you could use using [Android Assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=macos#reading-assets) to get StreamReader.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark your file as an AndroidAsset:

[image: Android Asset]

And then yes you can use something similar to this code:

```cs
AssetManager assets = ApplicationContext.Assets;
Stream stream = assets.Open(ConfigurationFilePath);
// Play with the stream and dispose it.
```

I explained something similar in an old article: [Xamarin - Loading configuration file](https://johnthiriet.com/xamarin-loading-a-configuration-file/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the using statement.
Try this code:

```
try{
   var _file = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "dictionary.txt");

   if(_file == null || !File.Exists(_file)){
      //file does not exist
   }
   
   string FileData = string.Empty;
   using(var reader = new StreamReader(_file, true)){
      string line;
      while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
         FileData = line;
      }
   }

   //

}catch(Exception ex){
 //Exception error
}
```

Comment: for me `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "dictionary.txt"` does not exist.

Comment: You can use "Xamarin.Essentials" 
// Get the path to a file on internal storage
_file = Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "dictionary.txt");
// Get the path to a file in the cache directory
_file = Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "dictionary.txt");

Comment: Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/